# Boulders in Valleys - Magnetic Confinement

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a "Boulders in Valleys" puzzle - it's been posted a few times on this site.  This specific puzzle's solution has an interesting property that made it quite hard to design.  The solution can be deduced logically (you should not need to guess and check).  It is similar to Slitherlink in that your goal is to create one continuous path that partitions the grid into two areas (note that this can be in the form of a closed loop, or a path that starts and ends along the grid boundary).

[image: The Puzzle]

[Penpa Link](https://swaroopg92.github.io/penpa-edit/?m=solve&p=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&a=PY9BDsUgCAXv4pqFPKUtZzHe/xo+hP8TEibTSaRrbYlp6o+ov6JNLqN/xXT+Y273YheoXo4W6Ml0wChm8/fkUT2/Y1gyHWb1dJh5QzhYNXSwfDccjLde5p1WPTcs74ydff5czD4=)

## Rules

### Curve Rules

1. The solution is a single, non-self-intersecting path that partitions the grid into two zones (whether by looping or starting and ending at the grid boundary)
2. The curve travels along grid edges (like Slitherlink) within the grid boundary
3. There is only one curve that fits the constraints

### Boulders in Valleys Clue Rules

1. There is a boulder at every number. The value of the number indicates the deepest depth the boulder could roll down to. It must roll down to this depth along at least one path, but it does not have to roll down to this depth along every path.
2. Arrows indicate direction of gravity for the boulder.
3. Grid boundary stops the boulder as if it were part of the curve.

### Mechanics of Rolling Boulders

*See below for a picture demonstrating the mechanics*

1. A boulder can roll “down” any corner, and fall straight “down” if there is no edge below it (“down” defined with respect to gravity).
2. A boulder cannot roll “up” (against gravity) a wall or along two “horizontal” (perpendicular to gravity) segments in a row (the hill would be too shallow!).
3. Boulders do not interfere with each other (i.e. they can pass through each other, overlap each other, etc)

[image: Demo]

This picture demonstrates the mechanics of rolling boulders.  The green squares show the path that the boulder rolls down.  Note that there are sometimes multiple possible paths, but **we only ever care about the one that rolls the deepest**.  The example outlined in red is an impossible situation, because a 1-boulder could roll down twice by falling to the right.

Comment: Shouldn't row 5, column 5 (e6 in algebraic chess notation) in your example be green?

Comment: Boulders can't roll down a path that is two long horizontally (we could instead say that the boulder stops rolling just before the edge, in which case we would mark it green, but I worried that it might confuse people into thinking the boulder could then continue to fall) - hope that clarifies things :)

Comment: Is there some site explaining in more detail what this puzzle is about, please? I was not able to easily find one.

Comment: @virolino this puzzle was originally created by the author. You can find similar puzzles in their profile.

Comment: Yes, as ACB mentions there's not much available online because I'm the only one who has made them (and it will probably, unfortunately, stay that way as the ruleset is quite unwieldy compared to similar puzzles).  Basically all information about the puzzle exists in just the 4 relevant posts on the Puzzling Stack Exchange.

Comment: What was the "interesting property" supposed to be?

Comment: @user2357112 I've written the interesting property in rot13: Gur cebcregl vf gung gur cngu qbrfa'g funer na rqtr (be iregrk) jvgu nal bs gur pyhrf.  To decode it you can paste it into https://rot13.com.  Sorry for the secrecy  But you'll agree the puzzle becomes trivial when this property is taken as a known fact.

I'm not sure how interesting this property is to solvers, but it was quite interesting to me as trying to design one of these puzzles to have it was very hard - I originally thought it was impossible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the completed grid:

> [image: final image]

The key to the success is

> 1s in between higher numbers.

Take a look at those 1s.

> [image: 2]
>
>  Their boundary should be directly below them, because otherwise they have to join with the adjacent numbers' paths which makes the ball roll down more than one cell; contradiction.

The next key step is

> opposing 1s.

One can easily see that

> those 1s should share the same border.
>
>  [image: 3]
>  [image: 4]

Things get easier after that.

> [image: 5]
>  [image: 6]

Here is a gif showing the rest of the process.

> [image: 7]

Comment: Great job!  It always amazes me how elegant of a solution people are able to do (and I very much respect the effort you put into making a gif :) )

Comment: Ooh nice, someone else has picked up [my gif technique](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/119426/5373) :-)

Comment: Thanks @BaileyA. Having tried your puzzles before made it easier :)

Comment: @Randal'Thor haha, this time I used my old method: taking screenshots and put them together, because there were not much images. (Penpa+ has screenshot option)